# Adding an image multiple times in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am stuck in an exercise for a MOOC. The instructions are the following:
"In this function the faces are created in a loop. The loop executes numberOfFaces times. In each iteration"

Five faces are supposed to show on the left side. However, I'm only getting one.

Below you can find my code. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong/how to fix it.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Matching Game</title>
    <style>
        img {position: absolute}
        div {width: 500px; height: 500px; position: absolute}
        #rightSide {left: 500px; border-left: 1px solid black}
    </style>
</head>
    <body id = "theBody" onload = "generateFaces()">
        <h1 id = "title">Matching Game</h1>
        <p id = "instructions"><b>Intructions:</b><br>
        Click on the extra smiling face on the left.
        Watch out though! If you click on the wrong place, it will be "Game Over"!</p>
        
        <div id = "leftSide"></div>
        <div id = "rightSide"></div>
        
        <script>
        var numberOfFaces = 5;
        var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");

        function generateFaces() {
            for(i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
                var smilies = document.createElement("img");
                smilies.src = "https://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
                
                var top_position = Math.random() * 400;
                top_position = Math.floor(top_position);
                var left_position = Math.random() * 400;
                left_position = Math.floor(left_position);
                
                theLeftSide.style.top = top_position + "px";
                theLeftSide.style.left = left_position + "px";
                theLeftSide.appendChild(smilies);
            }
            
        }
        
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Cheers,
J

Comment: Please copy the code into your question, not a picture of your code. Take a look at [mcve] for information about how to include the appropriate amount of code in a question.

Comment: Please post your code as part of the question (instead of an image of your code).

Comment: The code works for me. You must be doing something wrong somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Oc3RV3yLejBjEgNk3rrb?p=preview)

Your code snippet is good. This is complete thing:

```
 <html>
   <body>
     <div id="leftSide"></div>


     <script>
        var numberOfFaces = 5;
        var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
        generateFaces()
        function generateFaces() { // I need to fix this function. Something is wrong.
          for(i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
            var smilies = document.createElement("img");
            smilies.src = "https://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";

            var top_position = Math.random() * 400;
            top_position = Math.floor(top_position);
            var left_position = Math.random() * 400;
            left_position = Math.floor(left_position);

            theLeftSide.style.top = top_position + "px";
            theLeftSide.style.left = left_position + "px";
            theLeftSide.appendChild(smilies);
          }
        }
     </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

[image]

**EDIT:** actual problem discovered :)

Author was applying `div, img {position: absolute}` style, and signing `top`, `left` values to while outer `<div>`, instead of each `<img>`.

This fixes issue:

```
smilies.style.top = top_position + "px";
smilies.style.left = left_position + "px";
```

[Final Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/NugZ2E6kTY3i3fGcIi8I?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I'm doing something wrong elsewhere then.

Comment: Do you have any CSS applied to `leftSide ` element. Maybe elements are there, but they just overlapping each other?

Comment: `smilies.style.top = top_position + "px";
 smilies.style.left = left_position + "px";` - this is your actual problem. Check this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/NugZ2E6kTY3i3fGcIi8I?p=preview You were giving random position to `<div>`, not to `<img>`  P.S. upvote if it helped :)